# System out print incorrect. Possible Accessor or Mutator mistake

Tags: java

Having an issue with this section of code first stated below

```
  customer.setcustomerDiscount(customerPurchase);
  System.out.println("Percent off: "+ customer.getcustomerDiscount());
```

It is printing `"5%Percent off: 5%"`

But when I remove the front 5% the code will print `Percent off: null`

I am looking to find a way for it to instead print `"Percent off: 5%"`

Possible problem area is in the setter, and wondering if i should move the if else statement to have the getter grab it instead.

Working with the code and moving pieces around trying to solve the puzzle
code in its current state works perfectly other then that

Full Code

```
package driver2;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat; 

class Person{
private String name;
private String address;
private String number;
private double customerPurchase = 0;

//////// Constructors /////////
public Person(String name, String address, String number, int customerPurchase){
  this.name = name;
  this.address = address;
  this.number = number;
  this.customerPurchase = customerPurchase;
}

public Person(){}

//////// Accessors /////////
public String getName(){
  return this.name;
}
public String getAddress(){
  return this.address;
}
public String getNumber(){
  return this.number;
}
public double getcustomerPurchase(){
  return this.customerPurchase;
}

//////// Mutators /////////
public void setName(String n){
  this.name = n;
}
public void setAddress(String a){
  this.address = a;
}
public void setNumber(String n){
  this.number = n;
}
public void setcustomerPurchase(int a){
  this.customerPurchase = a;
}
public void setcustomerDiscount(int r)
{}
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Customer extends Person{
private String customerNumber;
private boolean recieveMail;
private String customerDiscount;

//////// Constructors /////////
public Customer(String name, String address, String number, String customerN, boolean rm, int customerPurchase) {
  super(name, address, number, customerPurchase);
  this.customerNumber = customerN;
  this.recieveMail = rm;
}
public Customer(){}

//////// Accessors /////////
public String getCustomerNumber(){
  return this.customerNumber;
}
public boolean getRecieveMail(){
  return this.recieveMail;
}
public String getcustomerDiscount(){
  return customerDiscount;
}

//////// Mutators /////////
public void setCustomerNumber(String c){
  this.customerNumber = c;
}
public void setRecieveMail(boolean r){
  this.recieveMail = r;
}
@Override
public void setcustomerDiscount(int r){
  String customerDiscount = "";
  if (r >= 2000){
    customerDiscount="10%";
      System.out.print("10%");
  }else if (r >= 1500){
    customerDiscount="7%";
      System.out.print("7%");
  }else if (r >= 1000){
    customerDiscount="6%";
      System.out.print("6%");
  }else if (r > 500){
    customerDiscount="5%";
      System.out.print("5%");
  }else{
      System.out.print("");
  }
  this.customerDiscount = customerDiscount;
}
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public class Driver2{
public static void main(String args[]){
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter name of customer:");
  String name1 = scanner.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Enter address of customer:");
  String address1 = scanner.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Enter phone number of customer:");
  String number1 = scanner.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Enter customer number:");
  String customerNumber = scanner.nextLine();
  System.out.print("Enter yes/no -- does the customer want to recieve mail?:");
  String answer = scanner.nextLine();
  boolean recieveMail = (answer.equals("yes"));
  System.out.print("Enter amount customer has spent:");
  int customerPurchase = scanner.nextInt();
  scanner.close();

  Customer customer = new Customer(name1, address1, number1, customerNumber, recieveMail, customerPurchase);

  System.out.println("\nCustomer: ");
  System.out.println("Name: "+customer.getName());
  System.out.println("Address: "+customer.getAddress());
  System.out.println("Phone Number: "+customer.getNumber());
  System.out.println("Customer Number: "+customer.getCustomerNumber());
  System.out.println("Recieve Mail?: "+customer.getRecieveMail());
  DecimalFormat ft = new DecimalFormat("####");
  ft = new DecimalFormat("$0.00"); 
  System.out.println("Amount Purchased: "+ft.format(customer.getcustomerPurchase()));
  customer.setcustomerDiscount(customerPurchase);
  System.out.println("Percent off: "+ customer.getcustomerDiscount());

}
}
```

Comment: The problem is that your `setcustomerDiscount` method does more than it is supposed to; it also prints the discount as a percentage. Delete the `System.out.print` statements from that method.

Comment: It also looks a lot like you just created a new account after having [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293143/printing-item-in-wrong-place) closed; instead of doing that, you should have edited your original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
customerDiscount="5%";
  System.out.print("5%"); // remove this
```

That prints the "5%" before you print the rest:

```
System.out.println("Percent off: "+ customer.getcustomerDiscount());
```

If you remove the first print (with "remove this" comment above), you'll print what you intended.